# Start intent with Serializable from within the serializable class

Tags: java, android, serializable

I am trying to start up an Intent from within a class which implements Serializable. I get a IOException which says "Parcelable encountered IOException wrinting Serializable object". This is what i am trying to do from within a method in the class implementing Serializable:

```
thisOffer = this;

row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, ActivityOffer.class);
    intent.putExtra("offer", thisOffer);

    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Everything works fine i take away the putExtra() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some field within your class which is not implementing `Serializable`

Comment: Thanks that is the problem. Do i have to extend all those classes and make them Serializable, there are many classes. Maybe its better to just send Strings with the information i need.

Comment: Yes, you do need to make them Serializable or use a custom serialization strategy using writeObject and readObject. If you can keep your data limited to strings that would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass whole activity in putExtra like this....

in the putextra method you can pass basic datatype and some other class...

just show the 2nd argument of putExtra method......

Comment: the putExtra method can take in a object which implements Serializable. I am not trying to send an Activity object, this class does not even extend Activity.